# How to run (or should I run) Composer on Openshift?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php, openshift

I am trying to create ZendFramework's Skeleton application on Openshift. I have created a PHP5 application using these [instructions](https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache) and cloned it locally. I cloned the ZendFramework skeleton application in the repository, then ran Composer to install dependencies locally.

I then pushed my repository to Openshift, but I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install`
or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in
/var/lib/openshift/559d4d8f500446844700002b/app-
root/runtime/repo/init_autoloader.php:51 Stack trace: #0
/var/lib/openshift/559d4d8f500446844700002b/app-
root/runtime/repo/public/index.php(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in
/var/lib/openshift/559d4d8f500446844700002b/app-
root/runtime/repo/init_autoloader.php on line 51
```

which is indicative that I need to run Composer on Openshift. How do I achieve this?

In my local repository, the `/vendor` directory is filled with dependency directories. However, `/vendor` is ignored in the commit. I could try to commit and push it, but is this the right way to proceed? It does not look clean.

Comment: Cant you login through ssh and run composer install in there? that will be Right way :)

Comment: I could try that, but that would not be automated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you need to execute `composer install` with each build automatically on OpenShift.

You might do this by adding a marker file named `use_composer` in the folder `.openshift/markers`.

`.openshift/markers/use_composer`

Referencing: https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-markers.html

---

If you need to do more than just `composer install`, like installing Composer, using `action_hooks` is the better choice. They allow to work with bash scripts.

See, https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html

`.openshift/action_hooks/build`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export COMPOSER_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.composer"

if [ ! -f "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar" ]; then
    curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
else
    php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar self-update
fi

( unset GIT_DIR ; cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR ; php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar install )
```

Comment: I have added the marker, but Composer is not executed. Maybe it's because it is not installed on this DYI cartridge... Grrr...

Comment: I have created an enhancement request: https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache/issues/2

Comment: Added a bash script for downloading and executing Composer as action_hook.

Comment: It's nearly working, but I am facing php version issue. I have opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478610/wrong-php-version-returned-in-openshift

Comment: Yes, the screenshot shows, that Composer is running on OpenShift. Glad you solved this problem.

Comment: i'm getting Signature mismatch, could not verify the phar file integrity

Comment: Odd. Are there any error messages during the Composer download? / Does the COMPOSER_HOME (`$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.composer`) folder exists?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install dependencies is from an action hook, i.e. a script run by the cartridge during the deployment. I would use the `deploy` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
# @file
#   .openshift/action_hooks/deploy

COMPOSER_DIR="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin"

function install_composer() {
    echo 'Installing Composer'

    if [ ! -d "$COMPOSER_DIR" ]
    then
        mkdir -p $COMPOSER_DIR
    fi

    curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=$COMPOSER_DIR
}

if [ ! -x "$COMPOSER_DIR/composer" ]
then
    install_composer
fi

$COMPOSER_DIR/composer self-update
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
$COMPOSER_DIR/composer install
```

Also remember to make this script executable: `chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy`.