# Wrong PHP version returned in Openshift

Tags: php, git, composer-php, openshift

I have created a PHP application (from scratch) using instructions available [here](https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache). In `/mish/make.sh`, the php version is 5.5.18. After the build, the php info page confirms the version: 5.5.18.

Yet, when I log in my Openshift application with SSH, `php --version` returns 5.3.3 with a wrong build date:

[image]

I discovered this issue when I tried to [install Composer on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473760/how-to-run-or-should-i-run-composer-on-openshift). I got an error message when git pushing back to Openshift:

[image]

I don't know whether the issue is related to the DYI cartridge or to Openshift itself. Does anyone know?

**Update**

From an email exchange with John Lamb, the solution was to include my PATH export in the `build` script as following (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473760/how-to-run-or-should-i-run-composer-on-openshift)):

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin/:${PATH}

export COMPOSER_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.composer"

if [ ! -f "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar" ]; then
    curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
else
    php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar self-update
fi

( unset GIT_DIR ; cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR ; php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar install )
```

Comment: Opened an issue to the cartridge too: https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited because I don't have enough points to comment:

Could you post your build hook script (`.openshift/action_hooks/build`)? laobubu's response should have solved your problem.

---

From my response to your bugzilla bug:
The custom PHP binary should be found at `$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime/bin/php`

Here's the steps I followed to make this work:

- `# rhc app-create p55test diy-0.1 --from-code'https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache.git'`

  ```
  Application Options
  -------------------
  Domain:      jltest
  Cartridges:  diy-0.1
  Source Code: https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache.git
  Gear Size:   default
  Scaling:     no

  Creating application 'p55test' ... done

    Disclaimer: This is an experimental cartridge that provides a way to try unsupported languages, frameworks, and middleware on OpenShift.

  Your application 'p55test' is now available.

    URL:        http://p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/
    SSH to:     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com

    Git remote: ssh://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/~/git/p55test.git/

  Run 'rhc show-app p55test' for more details about your app.
  ```
- `# curl 'http://p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/'`

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Installed</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Installed</h1>
  <p>You just created one amazing PHP5.5+Apache app.</p>
  <h2>Next...</h2>
  <p>
  <p>Follow the instruction on <a href=https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache>https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache</a>.
  <p>You can refresh this page to check if the world is ready.
  <p><a href=?doitnow>Come on, robot, you can do it automatically...</a><p>
  </p></body></html>
  ```
- `# curl 'http://p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/?doitnow'`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>302 Found</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Found</h1>
  <p>The document has moved <a href="./?working">here</a>.</p>
  <hr>
  <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com Port 80</address>
  </body></html>
  ```
- `# rhc ssh p55test`

  ```
  [p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]\> top
  ```
- wait for 'make.sh' to finish
- `[p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]\> $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/runtime/bin/php --version`

  ```
  PHP 5.5.18 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2015 10:33:49)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
  ```

Also, since I closed the ticket, I realized you can verify the version of PHP actually running the code from your repo like so:

- `# curl 'http://p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/?phpinfo'`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>302 Found</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Found</h1>
  <p>The document has moved <a href="./15541_PHPINFO_TEMP.php">here</a>.</p>
  <hr>
  <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com Port 80</address>
  </body></html>
  ```
- `# curl 'http://p55test-jltest.dev.rhcloud.com/15541_PHPINFO_TEMP.php' | grep -i 'php version'`

  ```
  ...snip...
  <h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.5.18</h1>
  <tr><td class="e">PHP Version </td><td class="v">5.5.18 </td></tr>
  ```

Comment: The solution you suggested in your email solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please see my additional response to the bug, in particular the custom cart dev links, which you might be interested in: https://developers.openshift.com/en/get-involved-extend-openshift.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version you build is not the active/used one.

You need to find out, in which folder your new PHP build lives and execute the binary over there. It seems PHP is build in the `misc` folder and not installed to the runtime folder. You might also alias it.

PHP should go into the runtime folder, e.g. `${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/php5/bin/php`.

---

A quick glance at your scripts reveals:

- you define `export OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime` in `/misc/common.sh`.
- you need to check, that PHP lands in runtime folder (is it in misc?)
- no alias for PHP, e.g. `alias php='${OPENSHIFT_RUNTIME_DIR}/php5/bin/php'`.

Comment: It is installed in the runtime folder. I have checked.

Answer (score 1):

Running `which php` in your terminal will yield `/usr/bin/php`, which means that the PHP 5.3.3 comes from the system , not your own build.

If you want to use your own PHP, run this command:

`export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/bin/:${PATH}`

If you are using openshift hooks ( under `.openshift/action_hooks` ), try adding the command into your hook scripts.

Comment: It does not work. It is as if the command is not taken into account.